Slingshot (Trajectory inference analysis )
I am getting this error while performing Trajectory Inference Analysis using Bioconductor Slingshot. I am not able to understand what the actual problem is. If anyone has any ideas, please help me.
I installed the packages required. I think there is a problem with a package--its version or the format of its data.
This is the error I'm getting:
> Error:- Error: [matrixStats (>= 1.2.0)] useNames = NA is defunct.
> Instead, specify either useNames = TRUE or useNames = FALSE. See also
> ?matrixStats::matrixStats.options


Make sure you provide a reproducible example. We don't know anything about what you've done, so can't provide much help based on what you're showing

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error suggests that in a recent change in the matrixStats package the use.names=NA became deprecated, so you would need to either upgrade slingshot, hoping that the developer made internal fixes to compensate for the issue, or downgrade matrixStats to a version before this deprecation happened. If any of that is possible I cannot tell because you do not provide package versions, code or sessionInfos.
